# what does clear do on airflow task?

Tags: airflow

When a airflow Dag's subtask gets failed, I had to `clear (Downstream, recursive)` before marking it to success so that subsequent job could run.

But I didnt get to understand what `clear` does here. Can anyone share in simple words ?

Answer (score 3):

Clearing a task changes its state to None (as you probably noticed it turns white first) and also sets max_tries to 0, which then causes the task to run again once.

The old task runs are not deleted though and you will still be able to access their logs if you select the previous attempt of the task in the grid view:

[image: screenshot of the Grid view after clearing a task once]

(I cleared the first task once, which created the attempt 2)

Clearing with downstream will also clear all depending tasks. Recursive will clear all tasks in the DAG run ([this doc might be helpful](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#re-run-tasks) to learn more about clearing options).